# rpmbuild can't change into directory

Tags: linux, redhat, rpm, rpmbuild

I have been trying to figure out how to build an rpm for the past 6 months and I still struggle trying to understand what I am missing with my build. My goal is to have my rpm install a tar.gz file.

Here is my .rpmmacros file

```
%_topdir      %(echo $HOME)/rpmbuild
%_smp_mflags  -j3
%__arch_install_post   /usr/lib/rpm/check-rpaths   /usr/lib/rpm/check-buildroot
%_tmppath  %{_topdir}/tmp
```

Here is my spec file

```
Summary: Appadm Monitoring
Name: AppadmQ
Version: 1
Release: 1
Source0: AppadmQ-1-1.tar.gz
License: GPL
Group: 
BuildArch: noarch
BuildRoot: %{_builddir}/%{name}_%{version}.%{release}-root/
%description
%prep
%setup -n AppadmQ-1
%build
%install
[ ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT} != "/" ] && rm -rf ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}
mkdir $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
if [ -d $RPM_BUILD_ROOT ]; then
   mkdir $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/tmp
   cp -af AppadmQ-1-1.tar.gz $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/tmp
   tar -xvzf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/tmp/AppadmQ-1-1.tar.gz
else
   echo "NO BUILD ROOT... nothing built."
   exit 1
fi;

%clean
[ ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT} != "/" ] && rm -rf ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}

%post
echo " "
echo "SUCCESS!"
%files
```

Here is what happens when I try to build the rpm

```
 Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /root/rpmbuild/tmp/rpm-tmp.sC0xn6
 + umask 022
 + cd /root/rpmbuild/BUILD
 + LANG=C
 + export LANG
 + unset DISPLAY
 + cd /root/rpmbuild/BUILD
 + rm -rf AppadmQ-1
 + /usr/bin/gzip -dc /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/AppadmQ-1-1.tar.gz
 + /bin/tar -xvvf -
 drwxr-xr-x appadm/appadm     0 2013-11-11 15:35 home/appadm/
 -rw-r--r-- appadm/users    121 2011-10-11 03:25 home/appadm/.kshrc
 drwxr-xr-x appadm/appadm     0 2013-07-17 18:07 home/appadm/orwell/
 -r--r--r-- appadm/users   1837 2009-12-01 16:07 home/appadm/orwell/irco_orwell_20004.stub
 -r--r--r-- appadm/users   1892 2010-10-22 15:07 home/appadm/orwell/irco_orwell_20052.stub
 -r--r--r-- appadm/users   1841 2009-12-01 16:07 home/appadm/orwell/irco_orwell_20003.stub
 -r--r--r-- appadm/users   1975 2010-11-04 22:52 home/appadm/orwell/irco_orwell_20053.stub
 -rw-r--r-- appadm/users    996 2011-03-29 16:07 home/appadm/orwell/sys_orwell_00409.stub
 -r--r--r-- appadm/users   3087 2011-12-30 14:06 home/appadm/orwell/irco_orwell_20032.stub
 -rw-r--r-- appadm/users   1098 2011-06-02 12:52 home/appadm/orwell/sys_orwell_00413.stub
 -rw-r--r-- appadm/users    994 2011-03-29 16:07 home/appadm/orwell/sys_orwell_00410.stub
 -r--r--r-- appadm/users   1159 2013-07-17 18:07 home/appadm/orwell/irco_orwell_20037.stub
 -rw-r--r-- appadm/users    994 2011-03-29 16:07 home/appadm/orwell/sys_orwell_00411.stub
 -r--r--r-- appadm/users   1535 2009-12-01 16:07 home/appadm/orwell/irco_orwell_20002.stub
 -r--r--r-- appadm/users     11 2013-07-02 18:31 home/appadm/lanetypeCksum_baseline
 drwxrwxr-x appadm/appadm     0 2013-11-11 15:19 home/appadm/rat/
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    406 2008-08-24 21:00 home/appadm/j7.sh
 -rw------- appadm/users     51 2013-01-30 17:24 home/appadm/.lesshst
 -rw-r----- appadm/users    276 2011-10-11 03:25 home/appadm/.profile
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users     53 2008-10-06 22:28 home/appadm/to2.sh
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    229 2008-11-03 17:27 home/appadm/ipl.sh
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    263 2008-10-16 16:26 home/appadm/longsql.sh
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    162 2008-10-06 21:51 home/appadm/to.sh
 drwxr-xr-x appadm/appadm     0 2013-11-11 15:10 home/appadm/logs/
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    160 2012-01-21 13:55 home/appadm/j.sh
 drwxr-xr-x appadm/appadm     0 2013-11-11 15:09 home/appadm/copient/
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    514 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/copient/ops_coptidy.pl
 -rw-r--r-- appadm/users     20 2011-12-22 09:50 home/appadm/copient/co_monitor2.txt
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    170 2005-09-28 10:53 home/appadm/copient/ops_chklog.sh
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users  23290 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/copient/ops_copiphourly.pl
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    610 2009-08-19 17:42 home/appadm/copient/ops_coptidy.sh
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users     65 2013-11-11 15:08 home/appadm/copient/copient_phpver.php
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    538 2008-12-10 17:00 home/appadm/copient/ops_appadm.exp
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    866 2010-01-21 14:17 home/appadm/copient/copIP.sh
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    706 2010-06-04 17:18 home/appadm/copient/ops_coproid.sh
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users   6413 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/copient/ops_copdiscount.pl
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    642 2009-06-09 11:09 home/appadm/copient/ops_copiphourly.sh
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    293 2008-11-18 17:16 home/appadm/copient/ops_cksum.sh
 -rwxr-xr-- appadm/users    688 2012-08-19 19:12 home/appadm/copient/dbCurebkup.sh
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users  21993 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/copient/ops_copresponse.pl
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    259 2006-01-09 19:58 home/appadm/copient/ops_appadm_survey.sh
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users   3553 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/copient/ops_copcard.pl
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    704 2010-02-12 09:46 home/appadm/copient/ops_copresponse.sh
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    670 2011-04-17 23:19 home/appadm/copient/ops_corpBrand.sh
 -rwxr--r-- appadm/users    111 2013-06-11 21:59 home/appadm/copient/c96766_EOC_fix.sh
 -rwxr--r-- appadm/users     73 2013-06-18 18:14 home/appadm/copient/IncentiveFetch_fix.sh
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users   2486 2012-10-08 14:21 home/appadm/copient/cop_cksum.sh
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    681 2010-08-13 14:35 home/appadm/copient/cop_incentiveFetch.sh
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users  13119 2012-10-08 14:21 home/appadm/copient/cksumList
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users   2571 2012-02-21 16:13 home/appadm/copient/toastClipStore.pl
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    357 2008-11-12 14:36 home/appadm/copient/ops_conf1.sh
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users   3865 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/copient/ops_cop_avg_roids_per_cust.pl
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    109 2006-04-17 11:40 home/appadm/copient/copient_ver.php
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    323 2008-11-11 16:28 home/appadm/copient/ops_pgsql_cksum.sh
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users  39326 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/copient/ops_corpBrands.pl
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    647 2010-08-19 16:18 home/appadm/copient/ops_copcard.sh
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    663 2005-05-31 15:53 home/appadm/copient/ops_copient.exp
 -rwxr-x--- appadm/users    691 2006-03-24 12:40 home/appadm/copient/terminals.pl
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users   6847 2013-08-23 15:42 home/appadm/copient/co_monitor2.sh
 -rw-r--r-- appadm/users   1310 2008-09-21 13:45 home/appadm/tidy.pl
 drwx------ appadm/appadm     0 2013-11-11 15:19 home/appadm/.ssh/
 drwxr----- appadm/appadm     0 2012-04-30 14:42 home/appadm/.pki/
 drwxr----- appadm/appadm     0 2012-04-30 14:42 home/appadm/.pki/nssdb/
 -rw------- appadm/users   9703 2013-10-21 14:29 home/appadm/.viminfo
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users   1955 2008-10-06 21:51 home/appadm/to.pl
 -rw------- appadm/users     30 2012-10-19 17:16 home/appadm/.php_history
 drwxr-xr-x appadm/appadm     0 2013-11-11 15:05 home/appadm/bin/
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    172 2007-07-16 18:30 home/appadm/bin/ops_chklog.sh
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    190 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/bin/ops_copPhonehome.sh
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    229 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/bin/ops_Q_coproid.sh
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    362 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/bin/ops_Q_copOld_customer_data.sh
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    292 2011-07-26 09:14 home/appadm/bin/ops_appadm.exp
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    167 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/bin/ops_copSanity.sh
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users   4483 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/bin/qtySCO.pl
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    607 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/bin/ops_Q_copLook_for_coupon_time_outs.sh
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    426 2011-08-12 18:20 home/appadm/bin/ops_appadm_ssh.exp
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    261 2007-07-16 18:30 home/appadm/bin/ops_appadm_survey.sh
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    215 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/bin/ops_Q_copBrand.sh
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users   1811 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/bin/ops_copCksum.sh
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    237 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/bin/ops_Q_coptidy.sh
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users  39646 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/bin/ops_Q.sh
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users   1238 2007-12-20 09:27 home/appadm/bin/ops_remote.pl
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    222 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/bin/ops_Q_copresponse.sh
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users   1297 2012-02-17 18:44 home/appadm/bin/cop_daily_IPL_time.sh
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    602 2011-07-27 18:09 home/appadm/bin/ops_appadm_scp.exp
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    206 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/bin/ops_Q_copcard.sh
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    665 2007-07-16 18:30 home/appadm/bin/ops_copient.exp
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    694 2007-07-16 18:30 home/appadm/bin/terminals.pl
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users   2736 2007-07-16 18:30 home/appadm/bin/co_monitor2.sh
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users   6305 2006-06-02 14:21 home/appadm/bin/ccp
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    217 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/bin/ops_Q_copiphourly.sh
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    501 2012-06-06 15:25 home/appadm/bin/ops_appadm_bb.exp
 -rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    785 2009-01-16 15:53 home/appadm/ops_emer.sh
 -rw-r----- appadm/users    281 2011-10-11 03:25 home/appadm/.bashrc
 -rw-r--r-- appadm/users   2535 2008-10-06 22:28 home/appadm/to2.pl
 -rw-r--r-- appadm/users    176 2011-10-11 03:25 home/appadm/.bash_profile
 -rw-r--r-- appadm/users   3205 2012-02-01 11:25 home/appadm/ipsort.pl
 + STATUS=0
 + '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
 + cd AppadmQ-1
 /root/rpmbuild/tmp/rpm-tmp.sC0xn6: line 38: cd: AppadmQ-1: No such file or directory
 error: Bad exit status from /root/rpmbuild/tmp/rpm-tmp.sC0xn6 (%prep)


 RPM build errors:
 Bad exit status from /root/rpmbuild/tmp/rpm-tmp.sC0xn6 (%prep)
```

Here are the contents of the tmp file

```
 #!/bin/sh

  RPM_SOURCE_DIR="/root/rpmbuild/SOURCES"
  RPM_BUILD_DIR="/root/rpmbuild/BUILD"
  RPM_OPT_FLAGS="-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic"
  RPM_ARCH="x86_64"
  RPM_OS="linux"
  export RPM_SOURCE_DIR RPM_BUILD_DIR RPM_OPT_FLAGS RPM_ARCH RPM_OS
  RPM_DOC_DIR="/usr/share/doc"
  export RPM_DOC_DIR
  RPM_PACKAGE_NAME="AppadmQ"
  RPM_PACKAGE_VERSION="1"
  RPM_PACKAGE_RELEASE="1"
  export RPM_PACKAGE_NAME RPM_PACKAGE_VERSION RPM_PACKAGE_RELEASE
  LANG=C
  export LANG
  unset CDPATH DISPLAY ||:
  RPM_BUILD_ROOT="/root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/AppadmQ-1-1.x86_64"
  export RPM_BUILD_ROOT

  PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig"
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH

  set -x
  umask 022
  cd "/root/rpmbuild/BUILD"
LANG=C
export LANG
unset DISPLAY

cd '/root/rpmbuild/BUILD'
rm -rf 'AppadmQ-1'
/usr/bin/gzip -dc '/root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/AppadmQ-1-1.tar.gz' | /bin/tar -xvvf -
STATUS=$?
if [ $STATUS -ne 0 ]; then
  exit $STATUS
fi
cd 'AppadmQ-1'
```

The command is failing because it can't cd into AppadmQ-1. I'm confused if that is something I need to manually build when I tarball up my directory I want installed. I thought it was build based on the Name, version and release in the spec file. I read on another thread that you need to create it in the setup. I tried that but it still fails. My tar.gz file source is created from all the contents of the /home/appadm directory. When I install the rpm I want that rpm to unpack that source code and overlay it onto my desitation servers /home/appadm directory so I can maintain version control of all the files and folders in that directory. Any help is greatly appreciated. if this question has already been answered in another thread, redirection to that thread is greatly appreciated or even a book I could read to have a better understanding of how this all works would be of great assistance.

#

@**glglgl** Thank you for the feedback, I really appreciate it. I made your suggested changes below.
I modified my spec file so the line now reads

```
%setup -c -n AppadmQ-1
```

Here is the output after I ran the command

```
Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /root/rpmbuild/tmp/rpm-tmp.Hl0evU
+ umask 022
+ cd /root/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ LANG=C
+ export LANG
+ unset DISPLAY
+ cd /root/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ rm -rf AppadmQ-1
+ /bin/mkdir -p AppadmQ-1
+ cd AppadmQ-1
+ /usr/bin/gzip -dc /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/AppadmQ-1-1.tar.gz
+ /bin/tar -xvvf -
drwxr-xr-x appadm/appadm     0 2013-11-11 15:35 home/appadm/
drwxr-xr-x                  Creating directory: home
-rw-r--r-- appadm/users    121 2011-10-11 03:25 home/appadm/.kshrc
drwxr-xr-x appadm/appadm     0 2013-07-17 18:07 home/appadm/orwell/
-r--r--r-- appadm/users   1837 2009-12-01 16:07 home/appadm/orwell/irco_orwell_20004.stub
-r--r--r-- appadm/users   1892 2010-10-22 15:07 home/appadm/orwell/irco_orwell_20052.stub
-r--r--r-- appadm/users   1841 2009-12-01 16:07 home/appadm/orwell/irco_orwell_20003.stub
-r--r--r-- appadm/users   1975 2010-11-04 22:52 home/appadm/orwell/irco_orwell_20053.stub
-rw-r--r-- appadm/users    996 2011-03-29 16:07 home/appadm/orwell/sys_orwell_00409.stub
-r--r--r-- appadm/users   3087 2011-12-30 14:06 home/appadm/orwell/irco_orwell_20032.stub
-rw-r--r-- appadm/users   1098 2011-06-02 12:52 home/appadm/orwell/sys_orwell_00413.stub
-rw-r--r-- appadm/users    994 2011-03-29 16:07 home/appadm/orwell/sys_orwell_00410.stub
-r--r--r-- appadm/users   1159 2013-07-17 18:07 home/appadm/orwell/irco_orwell_20037.stub
-rw-r--r-- appadm/users    994 2011-03-29 16:07 home/appadm/orwell/sys_orwell_00411.stub
-r--r--r-- appadm/users   1535 2009-12-01 16:07 home/appadm/orwell/irco_orwell_20002.stub
-r--r--r-- appadm/users     11 2013-07-02 18:31 home/appadm/lanetypeCksum_baseline
drwxrwxr-x appadm/appadm     0 2013-11-11 15:19 home/appadm/rat/
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    406 2008-08-24 21:00 home/appadm/j7.sh
-rw------- appadm/users     51 2013-01-30 17:24 home/appadm/.lesshst
-rw-r----- appadm/users    276 2011-10-11 03:25 home/appadm/.profile
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users     53 2008-10-06 22:28 home/appadm/to2.sh
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    229 2008-11-03 17:27 home/appadm/ipl.sh
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    263 2008-10-16 16:26 home/appadm/longsql.sh
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    162 2008-10-06 21:51 home/appadm/to.sh
drwxr-xr-x appadm/appadm     0 2013-11-11 15:10 home/appadm/logs/
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    160 2012-01-21 13:55 home/appadm/j.sh
drwxr-xr-x appadm/appadm     0 2013-11-11 15:09 home/appadm/copient/
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    514 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/copient/ops_coptidy.pl
-rw-r--r-- appadm/users     20 2011-12-22 09:50 home/appadm/copient/co_monitor2.txt
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    170 2005-09-28 10:53 home/appadm/copient/ops_chklog.sh
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users  23290 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/copient/ops_copiphourly.pl
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    610 2009-08-19 17:42 home/appadm/copient/ops_coptidy.sh
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users     65 2013-11-11 15:08 home/appadm/copient/copient_phpver.php
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    538 2008-12-10 17:00 home/appadm/copient/ops_appadm.exp
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    866 2010-01-21 14:17 home/appadm/copient/copIP.sh
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    706 2010-06-04 17:18 home/appadm/copient/ops_coproid.sh
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users   6413 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/copient/ops_copdiscount.pl
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    642 2009-06-09 11:09 home/appadm/copient/ops_copiphourly.sh
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    293 2008-11-18 17:16 home/appadm/copient/ops_cksum.sh
-rwxr-xr-- appadm/users    688 2012-08-19 19:12 home/appadm/copient/dbCurebkup.sh
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users  21993 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/copient/ops_copresponse.pl
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    259 2006-01-09 19:58 home/appadm/copient/ops_appadm_survey.sh
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users   3553 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/copient/ops_copcard.pl
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    704 2010-02-12 09:46 home/appadm/copient/ops_copresponse.sh
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    670 2011-04-17 23:19 home/appadm/copient/ops_corpBrand.sh
-rwxr--r-- appadm/users    111 2013-06-11 21:59 home/appadm/copient/c96766_EOC_fix.sh
-rwxr--r-- appadm/users     73 2013-06-18 18:14 home/appadm/copient/IncentiveFetch_fix.sh
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users   2486 2012-10-08 14:21 home/appadm/copient/cop_cksum.sh
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    681 2010-08-13 14:35 home/appadm/copient/cop_incentiveFetch.sh
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users  13119 2012-10-08 14:21 home/appadm/copient/cksumList
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users   2571 2012-02-21 16:13 home/appadm/copient/toastClipStore.pl
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    357 2008-11-12 14:36 home/appadm/copient/ops_conf1.sh
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users   3865 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/copient/ops_cop_avg_roids_per_cust.pl
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    109 2006-04-17 11:40 home/appadm/copient/copient_ver.php
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    323 2008-11-11 16:28 home/appadm/copient/ops_pgsql_cksum.sh
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users  39326 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/copient/ops_corpBrands.pl
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    647 2010-08-19 16:18 home/appadm/copient/ops_copcard.sh
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    663 2005-05-31 15:53 home/appadm/copient/ops_copient.exp
-rwxr-x--- appadm/users    691 2006-03-24 12:40 home/appadm/copient/terminals.pl
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users   6847 2013-08-23 15:42 home/appadm/copient/co_monitor2.sh
-rw-r--r-- appadm/users   1310 2008-09-21 13:45 home/appadm/tidy.pl
drwx------ appadm/appadm     0 2013-11-11 15:19 home/appadm/.ssh/
drwxr----- appadm/appadm     0 2012-04-30 14:42 home/appadm/.pki/
drwxr----- appadm/appadm     0 2012-04-30 14:42 home/appadm/.pki/nssdb/
-rw------- appadm/users   9703 2013-10-21 14:29 home/appadm/.viminfo
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users   1955 2008-10-06 21:51 home/appadm/to.pl
-rw------- appadm/users     30 2012-10-19 17:16 home/appadm/.php_history
drwxr-xr-x appadm/appadm     0 2013-11-11 15:05 home/appadm/bin/
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    172 2007-07-16 18:30 home/appadm/bin/ops_chklog.sh
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    190 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/bin/ops_copPhonehome.sh
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    229 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/bin/ops_Q_coproid.sh
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    362 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/bin/ops_Q_copOld_customer_data.sh
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    292 2011-07-26 09:14 home/appadm/bin/ops_appadm.exp
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    167 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/bin/ops_copSanity.sh
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users   4483 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/bin/qtySCO.pl
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    607 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/bin/ops_Q_copLook_for_coupon_time_outs.sh
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    426 2011-08-12 18:20 home/appadm/bin/ops_appadm_ssh.exp
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    261 2007-07-16 18:30 home/appadm/bin/ops_appadm_survey.sh
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    215 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/bin/ops_Q_copBrand.sh
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users   1811 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/bin/ops_copCksum.sh
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    237 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/bin/ops_Q_coptidy.sh
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users  39646 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/bin/ops_Q.sh
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users   1238 2007-12-20 09:27 home/appadm/bin/ops_remote.pl
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    222 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/bin/ops_Q_copresponse.sh
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users   1297 2012-02-17 18:44 home/appadm/bin/cop_daily_IPL_time.sh
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    602 2011-07-27 18:09 home/appadm/bin/ops_appadm_scp.exp
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    206 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/bin/ops_Q_copcard.sh
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    665 2007-07-16 18:30 home/appadm/bin/ops_copient.exp
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    694 2007-07-16 18:30 home/appadm/bin/terminals.pl
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users   2736 2007-07-16 18:30 home/appadm/bin/co_monitor2.sh
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users   6305 2006-06-02 14:21 home/appadm/bin/ccp
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    217 2013-10-30 18:45 home/appadm/bin/ops_Q_copiphourly.sh
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    501 2012-06-06 15:25 home/appadm/bin/ops_appadm_bb.exp
-rwxr-xr-x appadm/users    785 2009-01-16 15:53 home/appadm/ops_emer.sh
-rw-r----- appadm/users    281 2011-10-11 03:25 home/appadm/.bashrc
-rw-r--r-- appadm/users   2535 2008-10-06 22:28 home/appadm/to2.pl
-rw-r--r-- appadm/users    176 2011-10-11 03:25 home/appadm/.bash_profile
-rw-r--r-- appadm/users   3205 2012-02-01 11:25 home/appadm/ipsort.pl
+ STATUS=0
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
+ /bin/chmod -Rf a+rX,u+w,g-w,o-w .
+ exit 0
Executing(%build): /bin/sh -e /root/rpmbuild/tmp/rpm-tmp.5UPBZD
+ umask 022
+ cd /root/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ cd AppadmQ-1
+ LANG=C
+ export LANG
+ unset DISPLAY
+ exit 0
Executing(%install): /bin/sh -e /root/rpmbuild/tmp/rpm-tmp.7AYovn
+ umask 022
+ cd /root/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ '[' /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/AppadmQ-1-1.x86_64 '!=' / ']'
+ rm -rf /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/AppadmQ-1-1.x86_64
++ dirname /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/AppadmQ-1-1.x86_64
+ mkdir -p /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT
+ mkdir /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/AppadmQ-1-1.x86_64
+ cd AppadmQ-1
+ LANG=C
+ export LANG
+ unset DISPLAY
+ '[' /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/AppadmQ-1-1.x86_64 '!=' / ']'
+ rm -rf /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/AppadmQ-1-1.x86_64
+ mkdir /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/AppadmQ-1-1.x86_64
+ '[' -d /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/AppadmQ-1-1.x86_64 ']'
+ mkdir /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/AppadmQ-1-1.x86_64/tmp
+ cp -af AppadmQ-1-1.tar.gz /root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/AppadmQ-1-1.x86_64/tmp
cp: cannot stat `AppadmQ-1-1.tar.gz': No such file or directory
error: Bad exit status from /root/rpmbuild/tmp/rpm-tmp.7AYovn (%install)


RPM build errors:
    Bad exit status from /root/rpmbuild/tmp/rpm-tmp.7AYovn (%install)
```

I can see the directory was created on my server

```
[root@ tmp]#pwd
/root/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/AppadmQ-1-1.x86_64/tmp
[root@ tmp]#ls
```

The Source file is in the SOURCES directory. I assumed the rpmbuild command would copy that file into its temporary working directory from the SOURCES directory.

```
[root@j299848 SOURCES]#ls -la Ap*
-rw-r----- 1 root root 51158 Nov 11 15:54 AppadmQ-1-1.tar.gz
```

I guess what confuses me is how the temporary directories are created and used in the build process so I get a little lost in figuring out where my tar.gz should go and what I shoudld be naming things in my spec with the macros.

Comment: Your source tarball is ***nowhere*** near ready to be packaged. Organize it properly before attempting to progress any further.

Comment: Ignacio
What do you mean it is nowhere ready to be packaged? It is a simple AppadmQ.tar.gz that contain directories and files packaged together. I want me rpm to unpack it on a target server. Please let me know what I am missing. Many thanks and I always appreciate all feedback.

Comment: Take a look at other source tarballs to see what sort of organization they use. The more the better. Try to mimic them. And FFS, don't try to build packages out of someone's **home directory**.

Answer (score 2):

> The command is failing because it can't cd into AppadmQ-1.

Right. That is because you specified

```
%setup -n AppadmQ-1
```

which tells the [`%setup` script](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm-snapshot/s1-rpm-inside-macros.html) that, well, it is supposed to `cd AppadmQ-1`.

If you don't want that, don't tell it to do so.

If you want setup to `mkdir AppadmQ-1` before unpacking, do

```
    %setup -c -n AppadmQ-1
```

and your directory tree from the `.tar.gz` goes into that given subdirectory - which will as well be your working directory.

So, as you see, the `.tar.gz` file is unpacked during the `%prep` stagen via the `%setup` script.

Normally, this would be followed by some build process, but this seems not to be the case there.

Instead, that now follows is the `%install` process. It consists of putting all files which are supposed to be on the target system into the build root directory.

It could be done with a `cp` command. But, of course, not the `.tar.gz` file, but the unpacked directory tree:

```
cp -af . "$RPM_BUILD_ROOT" # I omit the tmp/ part because I think it is not the ight way to go.
```

Now you have a structure `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/home/...` which will be put to `/home/...` upon installing that RPM.

Note that you'll have to mention the files under the `%files` directive in order to have them included. Here you have the opportunity to give some user, group and even mode to the files.

But note further that installing files under `/home/...` will surely not be the way to go.

Normally, one puts packages with a completely own directory under `/opt/myapp/`, or distributes it under `/usr/`, `/var/`, `/srv` or wherever it suits.

And, one further advise: It is absolutely not recommended to run `rpmbuild` as root. That's part of the whole point: you prepare the files where they are intended to go, and pack them together. Only the process of installing the `.rpm` files requires root rights.

Comment: So my goal is to maintain code across all of our servers. That code currently sits in multiple directories under the target directory /home/appadm/. What I did was tarball that directory up into AppadmQ.tar.gz. When I copy my created rpm into one of these servers I maintain, for example an update, I want the rpm when it is installed to just unpack that AppadmQ.tar.gz which I'm assuming should become part of the completed rpm once I have run the buildrpm commmand. Thats why I added that unpack command because that's how I thought it was supposed to do it.

Comment: **glglgl**
I added more to my original post up top withe suggestion you gave me.

Comment: @user2985235 I elaborated further.

Comment: So I reread through the documentation and I think what was eluding me was the fact that the setup unpacks my tar.gz file for me and then in the build I just need to copy the files where they need to go. Thanks for everyone's help and comments.